# Soccer games for linux

Tags: games

Are there soccer games such as FIFA (from EA-Sports) for linux. Which one are open source, which just free but with closed code and which are commercial ones.

Answer (score 5):

There is a very good football game coming to final release in December. Its name is "Gameplay Football" and it is developed by "Properly Decent" studio. It is a free game that runs on MS Windows and Linux.

This is the official Web site:

http://www.properlydecent.com/

And here you can find more information:

http://www.moddb.com/games/gameplay-football

You can download a beta release. I tried to intall it on Ubuntu and I found some errors, but you can try anyway.

I think it is the best football game on Linux!

Regards.

Ariel

Answer (score 1):

By typing your question into Google, I found [Awesome Soccer Game](http://linuxgamingnews.org/2010/06/14/awesome-soccer-world-2010-released/#.UIvrOsXA9JE), which is a Linux-made game.

Answer (score 1):

Can't think of anything FIFA-like but still. As far as I know, the Football Manager series runs well on Linux. Specifically, you want to look at [Football Manager 2017](https://rawg.io/games/football-manager-2017) and [Football Manager 2018](https://rawg.io/games/football-manager-2018). These might be not action-y games but as management simulators they are very well-made. Also, there's [Foosball Street Edition](https://rawg.io/games/foosball-street-edition), which is on Linux too. Give it a shot if you want a more casual and cartoonish football.